# How can I find which answer was removed when a user is deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

Another "Dave enjoys spelunking" question.

I lost 40 rep points today because a user, or some users, were removed. Fine in itself.

Is there a way to determine:

1. Which user(s), and
2. Which answers?

Comment: I don't think so (except for mods). That would undermine anonymity of voting.

Comment: @DanielFischer How does voting come into play?

Comment: The reason you lost 40 rep is because the user's votes are invalidated when the user is deleted (if I'm not mistake).

Comment: @jadarnel27 Oh, I see what you mean. Except for one I lost 20 points, so unless the user voted twice... hence my assumption a question itself was deleted.

Comment: Well, if you lost `n` points due to a user being removed, you can infer that and how they voted on some of your posts.

Comment: There's also the closely related situation where a question is deleted, and you lose rep because your answer garnered some points. I think the answer is the same: there's no way to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to determine which user(s) were removed?

No, sorry.  Unless you get a private message from a moderator (which means that it was your sock puppet account that we removed), there's no way to know for certain which account caused you to lose reputation.  (It might not have been a sock puppet account at all.  Users do occasionally request account deletion.)

> Is there a way to determine which answers were removed?

It's possible that no answers were removed at all.  Most of the time when accounts are deleted, questions and answers stay behind.  Votes are removed along with everything else associated with the account.  Content is the only thing that stays.  (Just FYI, I'm looking at your reputation tab now, and even moderators don't get a link to exactly which questions and answers you lost reputation on.)

Comment: There are times I wish I was part of the cabal, both for informational questions, and just for the stories.

Comment: @DaveNewton We're not even allowed to tell the really interesting stories.  ;)

Comment: I know--it makes me mental sometimes, because I can imagine! I only like inside jokes when I'm inside.

Answer (score 4):

Short answers:

1. No
2. No

Longer answers:

1. Not without keeping a log of all users.
2. Not without keeping a log of all of your answers/question and who voted for them.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

As already mentioned, this could allow you to determine exactly which posts a specific user had voted on, you would just need to find out which user was deleted at that time, which is not that difficult for better known users.

And to correct a possible misunderstanding, this doesn't mean that posts have been removed, but that the votes belonging to the user have been removed.

Comment: How'd I lose 20 points on a single answer then?

Comment: Two upvotes = 20 points

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Right, the math I pretty much get. But if a single user was deleted I wouldn't lose 20 points on a single answer. This is what leads me to believe a question along with its answers was deleted.

Comment: @DaveNewton they could have voted on **2** (two)  of your answers.

Comment: @DaveNewton That was actually three users that were removed at the same time. Every one of those lines represents one deleted user, you just rarely see so many of them at the same time.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Right, again the math isn't really the problem. The rep report shows four entries, -10/-10/-20. You're suggesting they're aggregated randomly and that one entry could be for two separate answers?

Comment: @DaveNewton that **is** what I am suggesting.

Comment: @MadScientist Ah--I wondered about that, it just seemed really improbable. Roger.