# Identify question upon reputation loss from removed user

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

Understanding [reputation loss as a result of a user being removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted), it'd be nice to know specifically where that reputation was lost from.

Reputation changes typically cite where reputation was gained or lost; however, it's difficult to reference the origin of where it was lost when a user is removed:

> [image: user-removed]

Already labeled as *removed*, a link to the question would indicate the source of the loss, as in:

> -10     6 hours ago     removed     List component to bring up InputText boxes

Perhaps there's greater complexity here than I realize, such as the question itself being deleted; however, actions such as removing an upvote to a question or answer could be linked.

Comment: This kinda destroys the anonymity of votes.

Comment: Why would you need to know that other than curiosity?

Comment: You didn't loose the 10 points because the question or an answer was deleted; those 10 points you gained *from that user voting on your posts*. That vote was anonymous, and should *stay* anonymous.

Comment: @Mysticial How does that destroy anonymity of votes?  It's not the user, but the question.  Same as I know these other questions were voted upon.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed - I'm wondering what question lost the upvote.

Comment: @JasonSturges In the cases of larger removals where the user voted on multiple posts, they'd all appear together. So you know they all came from the same account - in some cases, who the person is. Example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156507/how-did-this-curious-undownvote-pattern-come-about

Comment: @Bart I'd like to know if malicious activity is occurring around my posts, or in general this functionality seems atypical to how reputation is generally presented.

Comment: Users being removed is not necessarily and indication of malicious activity though.

Comment: @Mysticial I can see your point regarding being able to identify the user based upon substantial change to the site.  Otherwise, it's no different than knowing a question received an upvote or downvote.

Comment: Martijn's answer is correct. We've had a couple of bugs that've inadvertently revealed parts of this, and the effects were not good (the bugs were fixed, but not before at least one person was gravely offended by having parts of his voting record revealed to all and sundry). As a general rule, anything that would reveal how another user has voted is a bug, not a feature.

Comment: Inverse of this question: [How can I find which answer was removed when a user is deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137771/how-can-i-find-which-answer-was-removed-when-a-user-is-deleted)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, because telling you what posts the votes were removed from would give you *much* more information about the removed voter than you have access to now.

You lost 10 points because the votes on still existing posts were removed. The user in question once voted an answer you made up, or voted on two questions you posted. Now that the user is deleted the votes are undone.

If the system did tell you what posts lost votes, you would be told that a specific user had voted for specific posts of yours, which ones they voted up, which ones they voted down. This could help you identify whom that user might be even.

Those votes were made anonymously, and they *stay* anonymous by only telling you that the user voting has been removed from the system.

Comment: Again, it is trying to understand which post the points were removed from.

Comment: @JasonSturges The point is more (correct  me if I'm wrong @martijn) that now you are potentially able to connect a removed user to votes totalling a score. (And this has happened before, with unfortunate consequences) With your proposal in place, you might additionally be able to connect a removed user to individual votes.

Comment: @Bart Yeah, I can see that.  Makes sense.

Comment: This is an incredibly ridiculous claim. You can tell just by comments, which people leave willingly, that they have upvoted or downvoted a question. It is no more revealing than comments to show which post the reputation was deducted from.

Comment: @Purmou The user indicating voting behaviour is significantly different from the system providing hints without a user's control.

Comment: @Purmou: If someone leaves a comment about voting, then that person has *choosen* to reveal their voting pattern voluntarily. And you only can take their word for it. There is a **big** difference between revealing your voting position yourself and having it revealed for you.

Comment: Wait, so when you are notified that this user upvoted your question (and you know it is that question because the system tells you), that doesn't reveal information, but when the upvote is removed by the user (or, in this case, removed due to the circumstances of the user being removed), it becomes revealing? This is illogical.

Comment: @Purmou: No, it is not. When you receive an upvote on a question, you do not know who voted for it. When a user is deleted, and *multiple* votes are removed, you suddenly have a *pattern*. If you had regular run-ins with a user for a specific set of subjects, you **will** be able to suss out who was removed, and how that person voted on your posts.

Comment: @Purmou If you receive an upvote, you don't know who it's from. If a user ends up leaving or is removed, his potentially significant number of votes, combined with his sudden absence, can be (and has been) very revealing.

Comment: @Bart: It is ridiculous to assume that just because a few people *might* investigate recently deleted users and make sense of the situation that every user will do the same. This is the same argument for having the favorites system: very few people actually use it, so does it need to be around? Yes, to appease those few people. If this happens to help a small population of users on the site disclose the identity of the voters, I see no issue in it.

Comment: @Purmou: Voting anonymity is **important**. You can't just waive it just because you don't think it'll be abused.

Comment: Okay, let's chew on that a bit. What do *you* personally believe is the reason that voting anonymity is important?

Comment: @Purmou You'd be surprised to see how active users become when a user with a significant number of votes disappears. This is not some theoretical possibility that never actually happens.

Comment: @Purmou: Because voting is important. Voting is the bread and butter of the whole system. Voting makes these Q&A sites **work**. And it works because you can rest assured that your votes are anonymous. Go read the rest of Meta here about the *dozens* of discussions on downvoting and 'having to comment when you do', etc.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. I know voting is important. Tell me why it's important that it remains anonymous.

Comment: @Bart: I understand that it happens, but I don't think that this request should be dismissed on the grounds that someone may or may not look into the issue further.

Comment: @Purmou: Read my comment again. Voting works because it is anonymous. There is no retaliation when you downvote a bad question or answer. There is no favoritism or feeling behoven to someone because of upvotes received. When you receive votes, they just *are*. Voting being anonymous is part of the fabric of the Stack Exchange series of sites, it is fundamental to the philosophy.

Comment: @Purmou It should be dismissed on the basis that it would potentially do harm to anonymity.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's the issue. Favoritism or, on the flipside, grudges. Can a user ever play favorites with a deleted user? Of course not. The user may end up knowing who voted, but they can do nothing with the information. They can't go and upvote that person's stuff since it is no longer attributed to that user.

Comment: @Purmou: Just because the account on a website is gone, the actual **person** is not. It may sound strange, but there apparently are actual people behind these accounts.

Comment: @Purmou You go explain that to [Mark Trapp for example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156507/how-did-this-curious-undownvote-pattern-come-about). Admittedly his anonymity was harmed by what was a bug. But the fact that users leave (for whatever reason) does not give us the right to say "you don't get to be anonymous any more".

Comment: Martijn, that is stupid. If they can no longer access that account, why should we put forth effort in protecting the anonymity of it? It is different with users who are not banned; they may eventually return.

Comment: @Purmou You (generic you) may run into the person behind the ex-account somewhere else. Or they may decide to create a new account here, if the removal was voluntary.

Comment: @Purmou: So, you feel that because some account was deleted they no longer deserve to have anonymity? Why does your need to have access to what posts lost votes count more heavily? Why do you care so much about what upvotes and downvotes were removed *exactly* that your need trumps the site philosophy that all votes should be anonymous? Just calling anonymity 'stupid' is not enough justification, in my option.

Comment: But that is too extreme a case to consider. What will they do? They know this person downvoted them, will they beat them to death? Jeez...these claims are all ridiculous. The two situations I see are this: you are banned for doing something wrong, or you ask to be banned. In the former, you, by the standards of the community, no longer deserve the privileges of membership, one of which is anonymity. In the latter, you willingly relinquish such. And, in any case, there are plenty of ways you can deduce who has downvoted you.

Comment: And then, if you return, you regain your anonymity with all future votes. And it's not like every single past vote will become publicized with your name. This is just a byproduct of the system. I'd like to know which answer of mine somebody agreed or disagreed with. It all contributes to the learning experience.

Comment: No no no. Anonymity does not stop at the door. We do not say "you're guaranteed anonymity as long as you're with us, but when you're out, all bets are off". That would be reprehensible.

Comment: @Bart: No, it is inherent. Once you join, you have the option to vote anonymously. Offsite, you can't put a sticky-note on something that says "downvote." It is an on-site privilege just by the nature of websites...

Comment: @Purmou: So that is where we disagree; you feel that anonymity is but a privilege to an account, to be revoked when you leave. To me, anonymity is part of the fabric of the site; not attached to the accounts, but to the system itself. At no point, **ever**, should the anonymity of voting be broken. This is not about protecting the account, it is about the freedom to vote in whatever direction you feel the need to vote, without fear that that anonymity will be broken *whatever the future may bring*.

Comment: Good God. You cannot vote without an account. Anonymity is BY ITS NATURE a privilege attached to an account.

But forget the nature of voting and anonymity. It just makes sense to show you which question/answer had the vote removed because it's your post and you always have the right to know the vote counts on your own posts. So which supersedes the other: poster privilege or voter privilege?

Comment: @Purmou: You can still visit all your own posts and see the vote count; that right is not diminished. You just don't get to connect that count with whom voted for you. End of.

Comment: Voter privilege. All the time. You've lost (or regained) the points anyway. Any additional information serves no purpose other than to satisfy a curiosity.

Comment: I think @Purmou is more implying to the intrinsics that the user identity no longer exists within the system.  Might be a different discussion if artifacts of the user are converted to a community user.

Comment: But this feature does not even directly enable you to do that. Just because it is an indirect effect of it, it should not be considered? Absurd.

Comment: Commenting is an indirect indicator of vote direction, should that be removed too?

Comment: @Purmou Once again, as stated before, that is a user who by himself decides to give up certain information. Which is a completely different scenario.

Comment: You guys are dwelling way too much on the rare possibilities that you have brought up. That's true about comments, @Bart, but either way, we don't even know that users would react that way with information about a deleted user. That which can be assumed without evidence can be dismissed without evidence. Hypotheticals get us nowhere.

Comment: And you guys still have issues with anonymity and grudges? A user can see if I vote to close their question and it eventually gets closed. That can certainly stir up some grudges. So don't tell me the system advocates anonymity, because the system now appears to contradict itself.

Comment: Definitely some grudges from the review system :D

Comment: I wonder, @Bart, wouldn't [your example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156507/how-did-this-curious-undownvote-pattern-come-about) also have revealed who voted *without* the question titles? All removals are registered at the same time, so belong to the same user; that's still a pattern. (Though indeed one cannot click through to see if there's any comment replies that might reveal a user name who is no longer in the comment threads.)

Comment: @Arjan Sure, a highly active, high rep user leaving, will more easily be connected with a single score total as well. But "this user might possibly have voted a lot" is different from "this user might have explicitly voted up or down for these questions". As Martijn said, it *"would give you much more information about the removed voter than you have access to now"*.

Comment: Wow, @Bart, after reading all above, only now indeed I realize *'[...] is different from "this user might have explicitly voted up or down for these questions"'*. (Agreed, very much, as anonymous voting is not only about who voted on whom, but also on *what*.)

Comment: Nothing here stops a motivated user from keeping a record (perhaps via the API, perhaps with a pen and paper) of from where their rep has accumulated and thereby linking for themselves the deleted users' votes.  If anonymity was **that** important, then votes of deleted accounts would not be unwound.  Seeing that the SO model implicitly accepts that anonymity should at times be sacrificed for other practical concerns, the debate is actually only one of degree.  And that is always going to be far more subjective than the vociferous arguments made above would suggest.

Comment: @eggyal: There is a balance to be struck between prevention of gaming the system (using sock-puppets to inflate your reputation unfairly) and anonymity. And note that your 'system' is hampered by delays; you are notified of score increases in batches through the API, you don't have the exact timings you'd need to reconstruct what votes were undone. It *may* work for someone with few posts and little change in reputation, but for a more active account you need to know the vote state of your posts at the time of the vote reversal, taking into account capped votes as well.

Comment: @eggyal: a determined user could also attempt to mine *all* user accounts and try and correlate when a `-1` penalty coincides with a downvote on your posts. And again it is delays and volume that will hamper such activity.