# The "User removed" message should link to a general explanation of this event

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, deleted-accounts

I found out today after losing 100 rep (probably one of the users of playorm who asks a lot of questions I imagine) that when a user is removed, I lose all the rep I gained from that user. It kinda bites but oh well.

It however took me a while to figure out what this meant and why I lost the reputation. Turning the "User removed" message in the reputation history into a link leading to a (or the canonical) Meta post containing an explanation, might help avoid this confusion. It would have prevented me from spending 15 minutes of my time trying to figure out why this happened.

Comment: Why would you want to know what reasons the user was removed for? Users aren't removed for malicious behavior—they're usually just suspended.

Comment: Um what does the last paragraph have to do with your request? It seems like a rant.

Comment: Nothing against you, but everyone has access to closed questions.

Comment: @HugoDozois: Please don't change the question like that. The OP clearly asked for a *different* link.

Comment: @slhck users can be removed for certain violations, as well as at their request; though that's still not relevant here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ? I might have not understood, but I only added a link to the question, I don't see how that was too much. I had added the link to the faq entry which is what I think he is asking. He do not want a link to the rep history as modified by slhck

Comment: @AndrewBarber I've suspended countless users for all kinds of things, even for hundreds of days, but I don't see a reason for *entirely removing* an account for violations. Fraudulent votes may be removed anyway, so what's the point in destroying an account over violations?

Comment: @HugoDozois: Hrm, I may have misunderstood what the OP wanted to link to here; between all the edits going on here.

Comment: @slhck forgot who you were.. hehe... I destroy/nuke Chinese vacation spammers all day long. As I said though, not relevant, here.

Comment: @dean A bit of an extensive edit there, but hopefully clarifying what you were getting at. Could you check? If it's wrong or too extensive, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @Bart looks fine to me.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not a bug.

You lost the points because the user voted on your posts, and now those votes are removed from the system. Even if there was something to link *to* (the user page is gone), you should not have access to that information because that would break voting anonymity.

See [Identify question upon reputation loss from removed user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177684).

Moreover, if a user misbehaves, the account usually is suspended or merged, not deleted. Most deletions are users that have requested that their account be removed.

Comment: I know why I lost the points.  My complaint was wasting 15 minutes finding out what "User Removed" meant instead of "User Removed" being a link to help that states "This means a bad user was removed so any points he previously gave you have now been taken away"  I am 100% others keep searching on the same issue wasting time all because there is not a simple link there.

Comment: It does *not* mean a bad user was removed. It only means a user was removed *for whatever reason*. That includes being removed on request by that user. I believe that that is actually the most common reason.

Comment: And your first revision was at best ambiguous as to what you wanted the text to link to; you marked it as a bug, and it seemed to me you wanted to know *what user* was removed, and why specifically the account is gone. That information is private and should remain so.

Answer (score 2):

We can't do what you're asking. We *could* probably do a better job of explaining what "user removed" means, but providing exact reasons isn't possible: not everyone gives a reason, and such reasons are private even when they do exist.

When users are removed for violating our terms of service, that too is a private matter. If the moderator or employee involved thinks you should know, they'll let you know.

Comment: We could make it link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it I think that would be great!

Comment: Linking the entry to somewhere that explains what it means would make a lot of sense, any time a user with a lot of votes is deleted on any site there are usually several posts asking what the hell this is all about

Comment: I don't want the specific reason.  I just want others to avoid the 15 minutes of searching around for what it means.  As simple link to help of "The bad user was removed who previously gave you points and so those points go away too(A bad user could be someone who does X, Y, or Z, or A, B, or C".  That would have helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous reasons why this could be an issue, but this one should be enough: the system and Stack Exchange's employees themselves might not even know why a given user was deleted. Any user can request to be deleted at any time for any reason or for no reason at all.